# Joi validation issue with min function

Tags: express, joi

I am using the following code in express.js using Joi and want to validate name length must be minimum 3 and must not be empty but minimum not working so required your help here.

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

//Define static array
const courses = [
  {id: 1, name:'course 1'},
  {id: 2, name:'course 2'},
  {id: 3, name:'course 3'},
];

app.get('/api/courses', (req, resp) => {
   resp.send(courses);
});

app.post('/api/courses', (req, resp) => {
   const schema = Joi.object({
     name: Joi.string()
           .max(3).required
           .messages({
               'string.max': 'Name should be max 3 characters..',
               'any.required': 'Name must not be empty...',
     }),
   }); 

   const { error } = schema.validate(req.body);

   if(error) {
     resp.status(400).json( {error: error.details[0].message});
     return;
   }
   const course = {
     id: courses.length + 1,
     name: req.body.name
   };

   courses.push(course);
   resp.send(course);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you said "name length must be minimum 3", but applied the max rule in your schema.

Also you forgot to add parentheses after required.

You need this schema with ``min, empty and required rules.

```js
  const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string()
      .min(3)
      .empty()
      .required()
      .messages({
        "string.min": `Name should be min {#limit} characters..`,
        "string.empty": "Name cannot be an empty field",
        "any.required": "Name is required"
      })
  });
```

**Case1**: without name field

Request:

```
{

}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": "Name is required"
}
```

**Case2**: name is empty

Request:

```
{
  "name": ""
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": "Name cannot be an empty field"
}
```

**Case3**: name is 2 characters

Request:

```
{
  "name": "AB"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": "Name should be min 3 characters.."
}
```

Also be sure you are sending request body, as raw JSON like this:

[image]

Also be sure you have this `Content-Type` header with value `application/json`

[image]

Comment: apologize actually i was testing the scenarios so copied the last code wtih max() but neither max nor min working anyway let me try what u have suggested.

Comment: @user342944 actually I already tried this schema in an express app and tested with postman. So if something goes wrong for you, please be sure your joi  schema is exactly the same as in the answer. Also please don't forget to mark and upvote the answer if it works.

Comment: i have made suggested changes and still getting Name is required error on all scenarios. I actually copy pasted your code but result is name is required.

Comment: @user342944 I tested this schema, you seem to make a mistake, can you add your post route temporarily to your question? Also show a screenshot how you send request body.

Comment: @user342944 I added a screenshot to show how to send request body in postman. Check if you send like that.

Comment: how to add screenshot here?

Comment: @user342944 or just compare with my screenshot in my answer.

Comment: Suleyman I am exactly doing the same and its weird i am not getting the same response.

Comment: @user342944 do you have Content-Type: application/json  in Headers tab in postman?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209435/discussion-between-user342944-and-suleymansah).